How to arrange cards side by side as far as space permits on both desktop and mobile?
There is a React component representing a card, which shall be in a similar grid view - if space allows;
function EngineerCard(engineer: EngineerDetail) {
  return (
    <div className='engineerCard'>
      <div>
        <img src={engineer.avatar}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>{engineer.name}</h4>
        <h5>{engineer.role}</h5>
        <p>{engineer.summary}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>f</button>
        <button>in</button>
        <button>g</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

And I employ the CSS as;
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.engineerCard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #2F2c34;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.engineerCard img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.engineerCard button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.engineerCard button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.engineerCard:last-child {
  background-color: #dfe432;
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
}

Which is resulting in this look;


Why is the yellow card footer misplaced, however the buttons - it contains - well positioned ?

Why the second card's background is white ?

Why isn't the CSS property justify-content: space-around; applied on the second card ?



have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

.engineerCard:last-child {   height: 30px; } it does what you ask for: 30px of height, content is just overflowing.

@mb21 sorry I altered the question a bit .

@G-Cyrillus straight up ? I am no longer sure that last-child referencing the last div , which contains the 3 buttons. I think I shall utilize a different CSS selector.

remove that height to check it out. I do not really understand the purpose ;)

@G-Cyrillus I intended to set a 30px footer.

okay, but we also see that yellow background, it is obviously not the footer ;)

According to MDN - The :last-child CSS pseudo-class represents the last element among a group of sibling elements. So, if u want to reference the last div, try .engineerCard div:last-child

actually, yes. or id="footer" might work as well.
